# Parsing JSON Object from a JSON array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am currently developing an app and need to parse JSON objects from inside an unnamed array.
I can only manage to parse JSON arrays with a name such as this one:  http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt.

The code that I used for the one above is

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }


            String asd = buffer.toString();

           JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(asd);
           JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");
           JSONObject fObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String movie = fObject.getString("movie");
            int year = fObject.getInt("year");

            return movie + year;
```

The code includes "movies" which is the array name .
What should I change to parse only the objects from within a JSON array such as  https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all?

Comment: You should ideally either return `buffer.toString()` or `parentObject` from `doInBackground`. Do the remaining JSON parsing in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Your countries list is simply an array. Doesn't need a name.

Simply replace

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(asd);
```

with

```
JSONArray parentObject = new JSONArray(asd);
```

See this post for how to iterate over that array to parse the remainder of the objects.

[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913)

Starting something like

```
for (int i=0; i < parentObject.length(); i++) {
```

Alternatively, Volley's `JsonArrayRequest` would be useful, or learning about Retrofit+Gson would be even better if you don't feel like manually parsing the JSON data yourself.